# npm start sb-admin-reactjs on command prompt

Tags: reactjs

i'll start the **sb-admin-reactjs** file on command prompt.it shows the error.how i resolve this error

> ```
> webpack: bundle is now VALID.
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000`enter code here`
>     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
>     at Server._listen2 (net.js:1259:14)
>     at listen (net.js:1295:10)
>     at Server.listen (net.js:1391:5)
>     at EventEmitter.listen (D:\sb-admin-react\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:617:24)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\sb-admin-react\build\webpack:\server.js:136:5)
>     at __webpack_require__ (D:\sb-admin-react\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap
> ```
>
> 5d42c3c1c657e355d54c:19:1)
>           at D:\sb-admin-react\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 5d42c3c1c657e355d54c:39:1
>           at Object. (D:\sb-admin-react\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap
>   5d42c3c1c657e355d54c:39:1)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>           at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>           at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
>           at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>           at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
>       D:\sb-admin-react\tools\runServer.js:71
>               throw new Error(`Server terminated unexpectedly with code: ${code} signal: ${signal}`);
>               ^
>
> ```
> Error: Server terminated unexpectedly with code: 1 signal: null
>     at ChildProcess.server.once (D:/sb-admin-react/tools/runServer.js:53:15)
>     at ChildProcess.g (events.js:291:16)
>     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! @ start: `babel-node tools/run start`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script 'babel-node tools/run start'.
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
> npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     babel-node tools/run start
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
> npm ERR!     npm bugs
> npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\picco_win10\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-03-28T06_19_54_258Z-debug.log
>
> D:\sb-admin-react>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix, you already have an instance of that project running on the same port.

Try to close all terminals you got open, and rerun the command.

This line here is a clear message:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000`enter code here`